# Swift: Split every item in JSON-Array into single file

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization, writetofile

I have a JSON-NSArray (created with `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers)`...), containing a few items and want to save **every item** in it as **a single file** on my local disk.

I've wrote the following function to save a local json-file:

```
func writeLocalFileFromString(dataString dataString: String, path: String, filename: String, type: String) {

    do {
        try dataString.writeToFile("\(path)/\(filename).\(type)", atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

So I tried to cast every json-item `as! String`. The files are created and they're containing a good-looking string, but however, they're not valid json-files. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop and get `every item` in `json` NSDictionary, then convert this item `json format`. Instead of `print` it as the code block below, you can save it to file as you want.

```
let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

// loop to get item   
for (key, value) in json {
     // data is a NSData contains your json string
     let data = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject([key, value], options: [])
     // convert NSData to String, then do what you want
     let string = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
     print(string)
}
```